# Crashing when using Firebase in iMessage extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, imessage

I am trying to use Firebase in a iOS app that has an iMessage extension. I have included the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file and I am able to use Firebase correctly in the host app.

However, when I include the following code in my iMessage app extension:

```
override func willBecomeActive(with conversation: MSConversation) {
    super.willBecomeActive(with: conversation)
    if(FIRApp.defaultApp() == nil){
       FIRApp.configure()
    }
}
```

The app crashes at run time with the following error

```
Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason:
'[FIRApp configure] could not find a valid GoogleServices-Info.plist in your project. 
Please download one from https://console.firebase.google.com/.'
```

What do I need to do to use Firebase in an iMessage app extension?

Comment: Your error is probably the most help you are gonna get... Make sure `GoogleService-Info.plist` has been included.

Comment: You are right, I didn't add it to the extension target! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have the appropriate Target boxes checked for Target Membership in the File Inspector. I've blanked out app names in the attached image, but this is what you should be looking for. Make sure your `GoogleServices-Info.plist` file is selected, then check off the appropriate Target Membership box. The specifics of your Target Membership will likely be different from what you see below, but you'll need at least one of them checked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also copy the plist file and paste it into the folder with the extension, the problem is that the file isn't accessible to the extention, it is only accessible to the main app.